# Remove the last character if it's DirectorySeparatorChar with C#

Tags: c#, string

I need to extract the path info using `Path.GetFileName()`, and this function doesn't work when the last character of the input string is DirectorySeparatorChar('/' or '\').

I came up with this code, but it's too lengthy. Is there a better way to go?

```
string lastCharString = fullPath.Substring (fullPath.Length-1);
char lastChar = lastCharString[0];

if (lastChar == Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) {
    fullPath = fullPath.Substring(0, fullPath.Length-1);
}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
fullPath = fullPath.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
```

Comment: This won't work with alternative directory path separator. You should do a fullPath.TrimEnd(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar) after this to not have a bug on paths like: "c:/path/"

Comment: Agreed, thanks. Probably `TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar)` in that case (to avoid iterating over the string twice).

Comment: What about "c:\" then return "c:" I don't think it is correct solution

Comment: @DušanKalivoda unrelated - the question explicitly WANTS to remove the last character in a string if it's a directory separator. If you care about the special case of passing the root of a Windows drive, then you need to check for that.

Comment: @BenjaminPodszun Yes you are right. For this question is your answer satisfactory because he wanted to use Path.GetFileName and this function have same return for "c:\" and "c:". But if he would like to only get path without worthless last separator then it will not satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 16):

```
// If the fullPath is not a root directory
if (Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath) != null)
    fullPath = fullPath.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar);
```

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Comment: No it should not be the top answer, it just regurgitates Ben Podszun's answer including the details in that answer's comments.

Comment: Well actually it should, since it leaves @"C:\" as is what I really like.

Answer (score 3):

```
string path1 =  @"c:\directory\";
string path2 = @"c:\directory\file.txt";
string path3 = @"c:\directory";

Console.WriteLine(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path1), Path.GetFileName(path1)));
Console.WriteLine(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path2), Path.GetFileName(path2)));
Console.WriteLine(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path3), Path.GetFileName(path3)));
```

Gives:

```
c:\directory
c:\directory\file.txt
c:\directory
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Ritch copy paste the code and try. It will give c:\directory. Ill update the sampel to include that.

Comment: Marino: Your original answer referred to `Path.GetDirectoryName` only. `Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\Directory")` returns "C:\\" as Ritch said. Your sample doesn't help, you just `Path.Combine` the directory ("C:\\") with the 'file' ("Directory") before printing..

Comment: @Benjamin does it matter if the code is combining a directory to a directory or a directory to a file? I thought that the result is the right path without a \

Comment: "C:\directory" will returns C:\directory - tested. "C:\directory\" will return C:\directory. "C:" and "C:\" - will fail!

Answer (score 3):

```
while(fullPath.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString())){
   fullPath = fullPath.Substring(0, fullPath.Length-1);
}
```

Comment: The parameter to the EndsWith() should be string, but char type input is given. So, I got an error (with Mono).

Comment: @prosseek  Yep, forgot to add the ToString()

Answer (score 0):

```
fullPath = Path.GetFileName(
    fullPath.Split(
        new [] { Path.DirectorySeparatorChar }, 
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
    ).Last()
)
```

Comment: What am I missing: In which case is the `Path.GetFileName()` still relevant, if you only keep the last element of the path anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Marino Šimić's answer and Dima's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6019339/13211180)  here is a solution which will not fail on `C:` and `C:\`:

```
var newPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(oldPath) ?? oldPath, Path.GetFileName(oldPath));
```